# what is the difference between these parameters in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, broker

I can't understand the differences between these parameters in Kafka:

- socket.receive.buffer.bytes
- replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes

and

- replica.fetch.min.bytes
- fetch.min.bytes (in consumer)

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you read the descriptions of the properties? What is unclear?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I read the descriptions of these properties but can't figure out their differences!. I think they do the same thing!! which I guess is incorrect.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I guess replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes is a buffer dedicated for replication stuff only and it is separate from socket.receive.buffer.bytes which is used when we write/read via producer/consumer. is it right?